# Insert now playing song into UILabel

Tags: ios

I have trouble with this code:

```
MPMediaItem *song = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *songArtist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
//UIImageView *artwork = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
self.titleLabel.text = self.songTitle;
self.artistLabel.text = self.songArtist;
```

It tells me "Property not found" ?!

But in my .h file I have both properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *artistLabel;
```

Comment: Post the exact error. The answer is probably contained within!

Comment: Remove self it will work nicely

Comment: Nice. Thank you! Again stupid ass human error :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably complaining about `self.songTitle` and `self.songArtist` which you didn't say were properties. change it to this:

```
self.titleLabel.text = songTitle;
self.artistLabel.text = songArtist;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `@synthesize songTitle` at the top of your main file you do not need to use the keyword, `self`.

Comment: That doesn't make it good practice. That's why if you don't use `@synthesize` the auto-generated instance variable doesn't do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you don't define songTitle and songArtist, try this:

```
self.titleLabel.text = songTitle;
self.artistLabel.text = songArtist;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the error is saying that you don't have defined properties for songTitle and songArtist. In your code both are local variables, so you can't access them through 'self'. Try it on this way instead:

```
MPMediaItem *song = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSString *songArtist = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];

self.titleLabel.text = songTitle;
self.artistLabel.text = songArtist;
```